# Converting Lambert Conformal Conic projected .las file to WGS84?

Tags: postgis, postgresql, coordinate-system, lidar

I am trying to import .las files in PostgreSQL database. The .las files are from https://viewer.nationalmap.gov/basic/?basemap=b1&category=ned,nedsrc&title=3DEP%20View. The issue is the file is in Lambert Conformal Conic projection and my remaining map data is in WGS84 projection.

I tried converting las file using las2las, but getting error:

> could not import coordinate system into OSRSpatialReference SetFromUserInput

I was following the tutorial https://gist.github.com/YKCzoli/3605e014b8ed09a571e5. But this tutorial does not talk about projection conversion.

Steps I followed:

1. las2txt -i SFdowntown.las -o SFdowntown.txt
2. copy elevation(x,y,z) FROM ‘~/Desktop/LiDARExtract/SFdowntown/SFdowntown.txt’ DELIMITERS ',';

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.

Comment: Which code/parameterization did you use when calling `las2las`?

Comment: I was using las2las with -a and -t parameter with source and target projections. I have already solved the problem by adding the data in postgres with las2txt and then using ST_Transform() function of postGIS. I was able to find lambert conical projection for Santa Clara county at: https://epsg.io/102643.